# python - Select date in a string

Tags: python, string, date, parsing, select

I am trying to make a code that selects the date(s) in a given string and parse these date(s) into ISO date. To parse the date into iso date i will use the dateutil.parser but i cant figure out how to select the date from given string.

This is the string i want to select the date from:

```
<h1 class="fluid">Friday March 20 (day #23)</h1>
```

I just want to select the "friday march 20" part from the string. I just can't figure out how to solve this.
This is the code I have at the moment:

```
  import dateutil.parser as parser

    def extract_date(h1):
        date = (parser.parse(h1))
        return(date.isoformat())[:10]

    test = "<h1 class=\"fluid\">Friday March 20 (day #23)</h1>"
    test2 = "Friday March 20"

    print extract_date(test2)
```

output: 2016-03-20

As you can see, the code works fine with the test2 string but i now need a code that selects the "Friday March 20" or maybe only "March 20"  from the test string

All help will be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Will your string always begin and end by the same substring? Eg. will all your string begin by `"<h1 class=\"fluid\">"`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the *HTML parser* to extract the `h1` element text and then split by `(`:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> data = '<h1 class="fluid">Friday March 20 (day #23)</h1>'
>>> text = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser").text
>>> desired_text = text.split(" (", 1)[0]
>>> desired_text
u'Friday March 20'
```

In this example, [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) package is used.

And then you can load it with `dateutil`:

```
>>> from dateutil.parser import parse
>>> parse(desired_text)
datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 20, 0, 0)
```

---

Note that [`xml.etree.ElementTree`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) from the standard library would also handle the parsing (in this particular case):

```
>>> import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
>>> ET.fromstring(data).text
'Friday March 20 (day #23)'
```

Comment: The date is set to 2016 since there is no year given in the text so i assume the default is 2016. I am analysing a website written in 2015 so is it possible to change the default year to 2015?

Comment: @CodeBeginner12 sure, provide a default `parse(desired_text, default=datetime(2015, 1, 1))`.